# psycopg2 takes a value as a column

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a table using psycopg2 and then insert outer data from some jsons. For this reason I defined 2 function: create_words_table() and insert_data():

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
    database="dbname",
    user="username",
    password="password",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port="5432"
)

cur = con.cursor()


def create_words_table():

    cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE WORDS 
        (word_ CHAR(50),
        POS_ CHAR(20),
        case_ CHAR(20),
        animacy_ CHAR(20),
        tense_ CHAR(20),
        person_ CHAR(20),
        number_ CHAR(20),
        gender_ CHAR(20),
        mood_ CHAR(20),
        tonality_ CHAR(20),
        POS_score_ REAL NOT NULL,
        NEU_score_ REAL NOT NULL,
        NEG_score_ REAL NOT NULL );""")

def insert_data(word):

    # handle_dict() is a function for getting outer data.

    if handle_dict(word) is not None:
        (word_from_dict, pos_from_dict, case_from_dict, gender_from_dict,
         mood_from_dict, number_from_dict, person_from_dict, tense_from_dict,
         tonality_from_dict, pos_score_from_dict, neu_score_from_dict,
         neg_score_from_dict) = handle_dict(word)

        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO WORDS (word_, POS_, case_, gender_, mood_, 
        number_, person_, tense_, tonality_, pos_score_, neu_score_, neg_score_)       
        VALUES (word_from_dict, pos_from_dict, case_from_dict, gender_from_dict, 
        mood_from_dict, number_from_dict, person_from_dict, tense_from_dict, 
        tonality_from_dict, pos_score_from_dict, neu_score_from_dict, 
        neg_score_from_dict)''')

        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

So, attempting to execute them:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_words_table()
    logger.info("table created")
    insert_data()
    logger.info("Records inserted successfully")
```

I got further error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\file", line 178, in <module>
    main()
  File "path\to\file", line 172, in main
    insert_data()
  File "path\to\file", line 148, in insert_data
    cur.execute('''
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: ОШИБКА:  столбец "word_from_dict" не существует 
                               # ERROR: column "word_from_dict" does not exist ###
LINE 4:         VALUES (word_from_dict, pos_from_dict, case_from_dic...
```

Looking at documentation, I don't see any mistake applying simple INSERT query and can't understand why psycopg2 takes a tuple after word VALUE as a table's fields.
If anybody could clear me this, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your query , you need to change your query to this and pass the tuple as param:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO WORDS (word_, POS_, case_, gender_, mood_, 
        number_, person_, tense_, tonality_, pos_score_, neu_score_, neg_score_) 
   VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',handle_dict(word))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Really, it takes 2 parametres. Just a little clarification: ```<...>, handle_dict(word)```